# Can you reduce protections below zero for an enemy god, creating a damage increase?

Tags: xbox-one, smite

Say I have an item that reduces magical protection by 10 for ten seconds, and you have 20 magical protection.

If I hit you two times, your magical protection should be at 0, meaning you would take the full damage of a magical attack, with no reduction.

**If I hit you again, will you take *increased* damage from a magical attack?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buff would not stack. They would only have the 10 protection reduction and you **CANNOT** go below 0 protections..